# How do I stop a bash script from the command line?

Tags: macos, bash

I have a bash script I use to run XCode on OS X, which takes several minutes. I can't find the key command to stop it if I realize an error... on DOS I'm used to <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> but neither seem to work. What am I looking for (on the standard OS X terminal)?

Comment: `ctrl C` should send sig-term (this signal can be trapped), and `ctrl z` send sig stop (both (all) key sequences can be blocked.) You need to set keyboard focus to terminal first. (this comment is for any generic Unix system)

Comment: @richard Ctrl-C sends SIGINT, not SIGTERM. SIGINT should terminate the process

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor `Ctrl+Z` sends SIGTSTP (which *can* be caught), not SIGSTOP (which *cannot* be caught).

Answer (score 7):

There are a few keypresses that should help you here.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> should send the foreground process SIGINT, and that should terminate the process unless you trap the signal with something like `trap INT ...` in your shell code.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> should send SIGSTOP, which would pause your process, again unless you trap your signals.

The mapping of key sequences jumps through some hoops, including terminal settings. What does `stty -a` say on your computer? Look in the output for `intr`, that's the keypress that should trigger SIGINT. If nothing is set, you need to set it, something like `stty intr ^C`

As others have said, you can kill the process from another window as well.

Comment: `Ctrl`+`Z` for the win, thank you! _(`Ctrl`+`C` wasn't working for me this time)_

Answer (score 1):

You can try these solutions :

- try this keyboard combo : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>
- open a new terminal and run `pkill -f script_name`

Comment: These are not applicable to OS X.

Answer (score 1):

If <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> isn't working for you, you can open a new Terminal tab and type

```
killall [process name]
```

where `[process name]` is the name of your bash script (you can find this in OS X's Activity Monitor).

Answer (score 0):

To add on to what other users have said, you can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> which sends `SIGQUIT` and is the same as `SIGINT` except it also produces a core dump. I've found that programs which ignore `SIGINT` often do not ignore `SIGQUIT`.

Based on the [man-page for kill](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/kill1.html), you are also able to send a `SIGTERM` or `SIGKILL` to any process. You would accomplish this by finding your process in the process table (type `ps`) and then type `kill -15 [pid]` to send a `SIGTERM` or `kill -9 [pid]` to send a `SIGKILL` (SIGKILL can't be ignored and will kill the process no matter what).

[Source 1](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html) and [Source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042201/how-does-sigint-relate-to-the-other-termination-signals-such-as-sigterm-sigquit)